# R package sf | Conversion from NAD83 is not working

Tags: r, mapping, gis, geospatial, r-sf

I want to plot specific points (stores) and see if they are in a buffer around schools in St. Louis, MO.

For whatever reason, I am not getting a clear conversion for the stores (at least the dots are not showing up) on the following example.

The coordinates for the stores are described as: "The XCoord and YCoord fields are X- and Y-coordinates of the I/Leads store location and in State Plane North American Datum 1983 (NAD83) format. This is a standard coordinate system for displaying regional/local geographic data in
any desktop mapping application. " **This is for St. Louis in MO.**

Two data points for the stores:

```
XCoord   |   YCoord

900378.4 | 1033497

882296.1 | 1034238
```

Here is my code:

```
county.sf <- get_acs(state = "MO",
                 county = c("St. Louis County", "St. Louis City"),
                 geography = "tract",
                 variables = "B03002_001", 
                 output="wide", 
                 geometry = TRUE) %>%
sf::st_transform(crs = "ESRI:102003")

school <- read.csv("C:\\file1.csv")
school.sf <- st_as_sf(school, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = "epsg:4326") 
school.sf.utm <- st_transform(school.sf, crs = "ESRI:102003")

#^^^This all works fine and graphs with appropriate buffer

store <- import("C:file2.csv")
store.sf <- st_as_sf(store, coords = c("XCoord", "YCoord"), crs ="epsg:6512") 
store.sf.utm <- st_transform(store.sf, crs = "ESRI:102003")

#These points are not showing up. There is more code but I think it is this code ^^^ that is wrong. 6512 is supposedly MO East, but something is wrong.
```

Comment: Without an API key I can't get your data, so I won't test your example. I assume you have code to plot `school.sf.utm` and `store.sf.utm`; it might be a good idea to share this incase this is the problem. First, I would check where `store.sf.utm` is being plotted (if anywhere) - are these in the right places on a map? If not, the original `crs` that you assign inside `st_as_sf()` may be incorrect. When plotting, I have found that `tmap` can handle data with different projections on the same map - this might also help. Please share the data for both `school` and `stores` if you need more help.

Comment: Hi Everyone, After a lot of experimentation, the correct code is "ESRI:102696" instead of "espg:6512."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation, i've found the correct code is
`"ESRI:102696"` instead
of `"espg:6512."`